# GPS locating takes too long to start

Tags: android, location

I set up a LocationManager in my app to locate the user and show his current position.
This is working fine, except of a too long starting time (sometimes >10sec). After the starting time, the service works as expected.

Here is a log output. The first line is the `LastKnownLocation` on startup, the LocationService is starting 18sec later...

```
05-04 09:14:29.301 23688-23688/xxxxx D/MainActivity: Moving GMaps to location Location[gps x,986175,x,121746 acc=14 et=+2d11h37m45s435ms alt=165.0 vel=0.0 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=40]}]
[...]
05-04 09:14:47.943 23688-23688/xxxxx D/MainActivity: Moving GMaps to location Location[gps x,986343,x,121702 acc=33 et=+2d11h40m57s443ms alt=149.0 vel=0.25 bear=139.8 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=40]}]
05-04 09:14:48.940 23688-23688/xxxxx D/MainActivity: Moving GMaps to location Location[gps x,986351,x,121693 acc=30 et=+2d11h40m58s442ms alt=134.0 vel=0.25 bear=139.8 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=40]}]
05-04 09:14:49.948 23688-23688/xxxxx D/MainActivity: Moving GMaps to location Location[gps x,986373,x,121666 acc=28 et=+2d11h40m59s448ms alt=160.0 vel=0.25 bear=139.8 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=40]}]
[...]
```

This is my current code:

onCreate:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment
        = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        onMyMapReady(googleMap);
    }
});
```

onMyMapReady:

```
private void onMyMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onMapLoaded() {
            askPermissionsAndShowMyLocation();
          }
      });
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
}
```

`askPermissionsAndShowMyLocation()` is a simple method to ask for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. On success (or below API 23) the method `showMyLocation()` will be called.

showMyLocation (as i can see in my logs, this will be called without any huge delay on startup):

```
private void showMyLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    String locationProvider = this.getEnabledLocationProvider();

    if (locationProvider == null) {
        dialogCheckGps();
        return;
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Location provider: " + locationProvider);

    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationProvider,
                0,
                0, this);

        currentLocation = mLocationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Show My Location Error:" + e.getMessage());
    }

    ///////////////////
    // This is the first log entry from above.
    ///////////////////
    if (currentLocation != null) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, ZOOM_LEVEL));
        moveToLocation(currentLocation);
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Location not found");
    }
}
```

onLocationChanged (this should be called immediately, but will be called with a delay as you can see in the logs above):

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    moveToLocation(location);
}
```

Anyone has a good fix to get the location updates faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's depend on Satellites fixed. GPS required at least 3-4  Satellites  fixed. If you're in Open sky then it's possible to get faster location using GPS

Comment: Thanks, and how do i get a faster locating?

Comment: This is totally nothing related to code. GPS signal may take long time to figure a GPS location simply because the weather is not good or you are indoor or your location is in a place where GPS is weak and you cannot make anything that my fasten this issue

Comment: better to use `Google Location Services`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of time it takes to get the GPS lock depends on the signal strength. However, there are a couple of things you could implement in order to make it seem "faster".

You have three different provider types:

**PASSIVE_PROVIDER**

Very fast lock

No extra power requirements

Low accuracy (unless in areas with many wireless access points) - ~ 1 mile

**NETWORK_PROVIDER**

Uses GPS + cell network to get a quick initial fix

Very low power

Pretty accurate - ~100 - 200ft

**GPS_PROVIDER**

Uses GPS and needs a long time to get a fix

Very accurate - ~10 - 20ft

Now you can start off by checking the lowest accuracy to highest accuracy, while you pinpoint their position on the map. However, you will have to check with the device to see if the network or provider access is available. You can do this using

```
    LocationManager.getProviders(boolean enabledOnly)    
    LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(String provider)
```

One way to represent this in the UI could be a further out zoom level and then re-centering and zooming in for a smooth transition as you try to get a better fix.

One more thing that I noticed, is that you are requesting your permissions after creating the map. Since it's an Async load you can start the LocationManager GPS pinpointing while the map is loading. You can do this in the onCreate portion of your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. I'll try my best :)